# VPS telnet 80 strange response

Tags: telnet

From my PC, I test a telnet connection to my VPS HOST (used from 2 php little websites) and I get a curious website response : plays-slot.com
So my question Why ? Is it pirated ?

```
telnet 193.XXX.XXX.XXX 80
Trying 193.XXX.XXX.XXX...
Connected to plays-slot.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: I forgot to ask. Is it a fixed IP address?

Answer (score 1):

If you administrate your own reverse DNS space, you might have problems.

If you are in a VPS/ISP provider, in more likelihood, it  might just be the reverse name of the previous customer. Ask your provider to correct it.